# how to convert a string data to JSX?

Tags: reactjs

i want to fetch a remote data, and this data is JSX template. i want to use this data to dynamic render html.

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQFG8.png)

Comment: How would you resolve dependencies in it? Are you assuming all dependencies will be known and you will pre-fetch them?

Comment: Still you will need to transpile the string into actual JS. Have a look at https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Input = require('./components/input.jsx')
var Button = require('./components/Button.jsx')
var Panel = require('./components/panel.jsx')
var Container = require('./components/container.jsx')
var Styles = require('./components/styles.jsx')
var Style = require('./components/style.jsx')

var LoadData = require('./lib/LoadData');

LoadData.load('life_nearby_food', function(string){
    // string may be link "<Container><Layout orientation="vertical" width="fill" height="wrap">...</Layout></Container>" etc
    var app = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return string;
        }
     });
 });
```